# ¿Cómo realizar un update desde la vista show con un switch?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo una tabla `pay_order`, en donde uno de sus campos llamado `isvalid` tipo boolean, necesita ser actualizado desde la vista show de cada orden de pago, para que con un switch cambie el estado de valido a no valido en la base de datos!

No tengo ideas claras de como hacerlo, las que se me ocurren, deben de llevar un botón enviar y no quiero que sea tipo formulario.

Necesito algo como por ejemplo: cuando tengo un listado de usuario en el index y con un switch, paso de true a false y viceversa su status a la vez que se actualiza en la base de datos.

Comment: Para eso deberías realizar una llamada asíncrona con ajax, ya sea usando el mismo `update` de tu controlador y modificando el campo `isvalid` a true o false, o creando un nuevo action en tu controlador que realice dicho cambio al llamarlo. Supongo googleando algo como `rails ajax update` te dará algunos buenos tutoriales que te indiquen como realizar esto

Answer (score 0):

¿Como estas?

Podrías usar las bondades de rails y colocar al formulario un remote true

o un enlace que haga una petición **POST** o **GET**, dependiendo lo que quieras.

Aquí te dejo la documentación de [hacer peticiones remotas](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements)

Saludos espero que te sirva!